# Vue js component and Chart js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have a component which count the number of a specific dice (eg 1,2,3,4,5,6) appeared. I want to export this counter to another component where this values will be used for making the Chart.

This is the Dice component

```
export default {
name: "RollDice",
data(){
  return{
    rolling: 0,
    interval: null,
    counter1:0,
    counter2:0,
    counter3:0,
    counter4:0,
    counter5:0,
    counter6:0,
    totalCounter:0
  };
},
methods:{
  rollOnce(){
    var rollingOnce= Math.ceil(Math.random()*6);
    this.rolling= rollingOnce;
    if(rollingOnce==1)
     this.counter1++;
    if(rollingOnce==2)
      this.counter2++;
    if(rollingOnce==3)
      this.counter3++;
    if(rollingOnce==4)
      this.counter4++;
    if(rollingOnce==5)
      this.counter5++;
    if(rollingOnce==6)
      this.counter6++;
  },
  keepRolling(){
    var timeInterval = 500;
    for (var i = 0; i <100; i++) {
      this.interval=setTimeout(this.rollOnce, i * timeInterval)
    }

    if(interval==1)
      this.counter1++;
    if(interval==2)
      this.counter2++;
    if(interval==3)
      this.counter3++;
    if(interval==4)
      this.counter4++;
    if(interval==5)
      this.counter5++;
    if(interval==6)
      this.counter6++;
  },
```

I want to export this counter1,counter2,counter3,counter4,counter5,counter6 to the Chart component and placed to y axis

Comment: The code looks repetitive. Why not have a child component to handle each counter?

Comment: child components for rollonce  and another components for keep rolling??

Comment: A component for each counter. I am assuming that you have used all these counters in your template and their functionality is somewhat similar.

Comment: I have got rid off the repetitive part, thank you. This counter is in a component. So i need to get this component result of multiple counter to the other component where the graph will has those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global store (Vuex) to store the counters there and make appropriate actions and mutations to mutate the store values. Those values can be accessible by any component.